# Смешение значений понятия "тон"

Tags: значение

Дурной тон. Хороший тон.

Слово "тон" имеет значение эмоционального окраса речи и характера поведения. Если употребить эти слова в отношении к речи, возникнет нежелательная двусмысленность? Это недопустимо?

Пример: Он выражался грубо, использовал бранные слова в своем письме ко мне. Дурной тон речи его оттолкнул меня от него.

Answer (score 1):

Само по себе использование табуированной лексики не является признаком дурного тона. Она постоянно употребляется и в высшем обществе и даже в научной среде -- не говоря уже о людях искусства.

Атрибутом дурного тона является употребление табуированных слов именно в неподобающей обстановке (в присутствии детей или в разговоре с дамами или в телевизионном интервью). Вообще, дурной тон -- это всё то, что может доставить неудобство собеседнику. Например, затрагивание тем, щекотливых для него или для кого-то из присутствующих. Громко сморкаться за обеденным столом -- это тоже дурной тон (даже в рабочей столовке).

Comment: В этом смысле в ряде случаев обсценную лексику все же можно назвать дурным тоном. Например, если она употреблена в письме к даме. Верно?

Comment: @Владимир 
В письмах к даме такую лексику действительно не используют (за вычетом ситуации, когда письмо несёт обвинение в адюльтере).

Answer (score 0):

Бранные слова - это не дурной тон речи, это просто грубость и невоспитанность. Дурной тон (моветон) - это отсутствие культуры в манере поведения. **В речи, т.е. в речевом общении, тоже может быть дурной тон.** Например, светская беседа предполагает, что существует ряд запретных тем для всеобщего обсуждения. Это религия, политика и здоровье. Очень неприлично спрашивать о стоимости имущества, одежды или аксессуаров - это моветон (дурной тон).

В Вашем случае корректно сказать: *Он выражался грубо, использовал бранные слова в своем письме ко мне. Грубость и невоспитанность  оттолкнули меня от него.*

Comment: А разве выражаться прилично? Разве в светском обществе не существует табу на бранные выражения? Разве их употребление может быть совместимо с культурой поведения?

Comment: Вот именно - с культурой поведения, это не дурной тон речи, а просто характеристика невоспитанного человека. Дурной тон - речь о поведении культурных людей (светское общество), их ошибках в общении, а не о манере поведения хамов, таких в культурное общество не пускают, бранные слова присущи речи только низшего общества - черни. К ним неприменимо сочетание "дурной тон".

Comment: То есть дурной тон может быть выражен в поведении только людей воспитанных, учтивых, но в какой-то момент допустивших ошибку? О человеке, которого принимают за "своего" интеллигентные люди, но он нарушает некоторые приличия?

Comment: Ну, да. Это же правила поведения в культурном обществе.